# Delphi DLL Project does not find unit in custom BPL except when "Link with Runtime Packages" is True

Tags: delphi

I have a DLL project that has a dependency on another project of mine, which is packaged in a BPL.

In Delphi, when trying to compile the DLL project, it will not find the Units in the BPL, although the BPL is in the Search Path.

The weird thing is that when I check "Link with Runtime Libraries" then it compiles fine. However, that has other disadvantages, so I'd like to set it that to false.

Any advice?

Comment: You can't use code in a package (BPL) without using run-time packages. If you don't want to use packages, provide the .dcu file where the compiler can find it, so it can be linked into your executable. You can't have it both ways (don't use runtime packages but use your own runtime package); the code to support loading your package is in the RTL/VCL runtime packages, so they're required in order to use yours.

Answer (score 0):

The BPL is not used by the compiler, neither with or without runtime packages. When compiling with runtime packages, the DCP is used (which obviously is in the search path then). Without runtime packages you have to provide the DCU or PAS files.